# HOsting 2 http servers on the same server

Tags: iis, php, virtualization, hosting, asp.net

what is the requirement to be able to run PHP and ASP.net on the same server?

i mean is it possible to provide 2 hosting models one for users that have ASP,NET websites and other for users use PHP and other Apache stuff on the same server or with one HTTP Server

thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can run PHP on IIS, [numerous guides](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php) exist on this topic. On the other side of the fence, if your using a Linux system with Apache you can use [Mono and XSP](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET) to provide near complete ASP.Net 2.0 support.

Comment: Thank you.

actually we are planning to use Linux based web server.
what i understand from you is that after preparing the server with Apache and PHP then i go with configuring MONO and XSP to enable asp.net websites to be hosted successfully as well on the same server?

Comment: Apache can handle ASP.NET via Mono the same way it can handle PHP. You just install the corresponding modules and configure those for your needs. This will only require one HTTP server that forwards all requests either to PHP or Mono and delivers the result.

Comment: Ahh, it has been a while since I tried Apache/Mono. Good to know its now available as a module and not just a fcgi service.

Comment: does it fully support asp.net.. is it stable at production time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, IIS can support running numerous simultaneous frameworks. .NET/ASP/PHP/SSI/ISAPI etc..

You just have to enable them. http://www.visualwin.com/ASP/